# Problems with custom field name and webservices

Tags: rally

I'm using Rally SOAP API to perform a query given a value for a custom field, via Java.

I get the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x1f' after 'return code:  401
' is not a valid XML character."

I've taken a look at the custom field name (name, not display name) and it has some blank chars in it. Can it be this the problem?

If yes, is it a safe operation to rename the custom field, since it is already in use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can always URLEncode anything that you are trying to send to your webservice, though it sounds like it may NOT be your problem

Comment: thank you for the comment, but I already tried and it doesnt work. Anyway I suppose that in the grammar of Rally queries should not be allowed to have identifiers with spaces in it (it makes sense in every language of the world, actually), so I'm surprised that it is possible to assign such identifiers to custom fields in the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using the Java Toolkit for Rally REST API?

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api

REST is less brittle than SOAP and is the preferred way to access Rally's web services.